# Evento MySQL para bloquear usuario com x denuncias

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela de denuncias onde gravo as informaçoes dos usuários que denunciaram e quem eles denunciaram

```
   id | user   |   denunciado
    1 | userx  |   userY
    2 | userz  |   userY
```

e por aí vai, agora gostaria de fazer um evento diário no mysql que verificasse se o numero de vezes que o usuario foi denunciado é maior do que um numero X de denuncias para poder bloquear o mesmo

Vou fazer uma verificação 1 vez por dia, apenas ja que tem muitas pessoas que gostam de "floodar" nas denuncias

Resolvi da seguinte forma

```
UPDATE usuarios SET cadastro=3 WHERE 
id IN (SELECT 
denunciado
FROM denuncias
GROUP BY denunciado
HAVING COUNT(*) > 30)
```

Dentro de um evento que vai rodar as 3 da manhã de cada dia

Realmente, não sou bom em fazer as perguntas, eu não teria entendido o que eu estou perguntando se fosse responder essa pergunta, porém foi a unica forma que eu consegui me expressar, se alguém tiver uma sugestão baseada na resposta e na pergunta pode editar pra ajudar outros membros da comunidade

Comment: Enquanto eu respondia, percebi que a pergunta não é muito clara. Você poderia editá-la para esclarecer se quer o que eu respondi com as duas primeiras queries, o que eu respondi com a terceira, ou se é alguma outra coisa?

Comment: Você poderia criar uma trigger para verificar se caso o usuário tivesse número >= x o seu status poderia alterar. [=

Comment: Outro fator assim que fiquei na dúvida, é por dia ? ou seja, tem uma data envolvida ?

Comment: depende @Fúlvio é executada 1 vez ao dia, mas não é avaliado se o usuario foi denunciado x vezes naquele dia e sim num total de denuncias desde que se registrou

Comment: Entendi @RodrigoBorth ... vlw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você só precisa contar os resultados:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS denuncias
FROM tabela
WHERE denunciado = 'userY'
```

Ou, se quiser a resposta já na query (exemplo para maior que 5 denúncias):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bloquear
FROM tabela
WHERE denunciado = 'userY'
```

Se precisar disso para vários usuários simultaneamente, use um agrupamento:

```
SELECT 
    denunciado,
    COUNT(*) AS denuncias
FROM tabela
GROUP BY denunciado
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

Comment: perfeito, ja acoplei dentro de um update e saiu funcionando redondinho :D... Não conhecia a o ´HAVING´ ainda

Comment: a primeira e a terceira query me ajudaram a resolver o problema, a primeira porque com ela eu entendi a logica a terceira pq era a aplicação da logica pronta

Comment: @RodrigoBorth O `HAVING` é uma espécie de `WHERE` sobre colunas agregadas (no caso, o `COUNT(*)`, que é o total de denúncias por denunciado).